# JavaScript - iterate through an array and replace words on the page

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom

I have an array called "words" that is structured like this:

```
Object {text: "house", frequency: 220}
Object {text: "wow", frequency: 193}
Object {text: "language", frequency: 164}
Object {text: "cars", frequency: 73}
Object {text: "computer", frequency: 46}
Object {text: "plane", frequency: 38}
Object {text: "maple", frequency: 35}
Object {text: "tree", frequency: 32}
Object {text: "door", frequency: 30}
Object {text: "carpet", frequency: 27}
Object {text: "windows", frequency: 26}
Object {text: "floor", frequency: 25}
Object {text: "roof", frequency: 22}
Object {text: "ceiling", frequency: 21}
Object {text: "barge", frequency: 21}
Object {text: "wave", frequency: 20}
Object {text: "example", frequency: 20}
Object {text: "boat", frequency: 20}
Object {text: "ear", frequency: 20}
Object {text: "sky", frequency: 19}
Object {text: "chin", frequency: 18}
Object {text: "mashed", frequency: 18}
Object {text: "broke", frequency: 18}
Object {text: "impossible", frequency: 18}
Object {text: "well", frequency: 18}
```

I need to go through the entire array, replacing each word from the text: parameter with the frequency value on the current web page.

Example using data from array above:

a blank webpage that just says:

```
Wow, I can't believe the computer she had! It was loud enough to shake the house!
```

after running the script the page would say:

```
193, I can't believe the 46 she had! It was loud enough to shake the 220!
```

I understand how to access each element in the array, but I dont know how to grab the parameter to target words on the current page, and then how to grab the 2nd parameter to use as the replacement.

```
words.forEach(function(bla) { console.log(bla); });
```

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried anything? can you post the code?

Comment: To improve your question, please read this: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please edit your question--placing it in the comments isn't effective.

Comment: I prefer to use lodash

Answer (score 0):

To your comment here is how you can grab the relevant properties from the array:

[JSBin example with logging](https://jsbin.com/yemoki/2/edit?js,console)

```
var a = [{text: "house", frequency: 220},
 {text: "wow", frequency: 193},
 {text: "language", frequency: 164}];

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  // use a for loop to loop through the array
  // now grab each item:
  var item = a[i];
  // grab the text:
  var text = item.text;
  var frequency = item.frequency;

  console.log(text, frequency);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First convert your array of objects to an object of format `{ wow: 193 }`. This makes the search/replace easier.

```
var obj = arr.reduce(function(p, c) {
  p[c.text] = c.frequency;
  return p;
}, {});
```

(Based on my demo) Grab your text, and split it into an array, and specify an output element.

```
var txtArr = document.getElementById('body').textContent.split(' ');
var out = document.getElementById('out');
```

Process the text. For each `word` match the letters without extraneous punctuation, and if it matches an object key, return the replaced string, otherwise return the word. Finally `join` the processed word array.

```
var processed = txtArr.map(function (word) {
  var w = word.match(/[a-zA-Z]+/g)[0];
  var temp = w.toLowerCase();
  if (obj[temp]) return word.replace(w, obj[temp]);
  return word;
}).join(' ');
```

Then just add the processed content to the output element.

```
out.textContent = processed;
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/toe0bkur/)

Comment: Hey Andy thanks, I was able to implement most of this, but I cant get it to replace the words in the current page.  Not wanting to put everything in a new div but actually replace it on the current page.

Comment: Is everything in different elements, or all just within `<body>` with no child elements?

Comment: different elements -- I was grabbing currently with: 
`foo = document.body.textContent.toLowerCase().trim().split(' ');`

which might not be the best way cause im seeing some words in my array that are more than 1 word or include special characters etc

Comment: Well, my answer was based on your question parameter of a "blank webpage". If you want the text to remain in those elements you will have to iterate over all the elements but that would be very intensive.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Using Loadash 
SIMPLE    
var hash = _.zipObject(_.map(arrayOfWords, 'text'), _.map(arrayOfWords, 'frequency'));
var outputString = _.map(_.words(sentence), function (word) {return b[word.toLowerCase()] || word})

// Here Hash is the key value of text and frequency.
// The sentence is just the string sentence.
```